# Nullable reference types and MSTest ClassInitialize

Tags: c#, mstest, nullable-reference-types

MSTest offers a `[ClassInitialize]` attribute, which can be placed on a `static` method to provide one-time initialization.

Assume I have a static member in a test class that I wish to initialize in such `[ClassInitialize]` method. How can I mark that it's not nullable?

For example, consider the following code:

```
private static Database _database;

[ClassInitialize]
public static void InitializeClass(TestContext testContext)
{
    _database = new Database();
}
```

With `#nullable enable`, I get a very understandable warning: CS8618    `Non-nullable field '_database' must contain a non-null value when exiting constructor. Consider declaring the field as nullable.`

I could move the initialization to the constructor (but it would happen for each test method). I could use the null-forgiving operator (`!`). Are there better options to mark that `_database` is not null?

Comment: If `new Database()` is expected to never fail, consider setting it in the static constructor

Answer (score 5):

I prefer to use null forgiving in situations like this. Specifically, you can just set properties you know will be populated, but the compiler can't pick up using `null!`.

For example:

```
private static Database _database = null!;
```

Comment: I'm surprised this is valid code. If you're just saying the complier is wrong, might as well you not just disable the warnings via pragma?

Comment: I can see two issues with using pragma or other systems for managing this kind of issue. The first is that you actually need to include the comments in your code to disable, which can make things messy if you are trying to write self-documenting code and minimizing comments. The other, is that it applies to entire blocks of code, which could be a benefit rather than a drawback if you have multiple lines of code you need to apply this to.

Comment: A good example of where this might be more commonly used is in .net unit testing. This kind of syntax can be used to create properties used in multiple tests that can be assigned in a function marked with ClassInitialize. Since they aren't being set in a constructor, your IDE most likely would identify this as an error. By setting the values to null! you are essentially telling the IDE to trust your decision.

Comment: One final example I will include is that this can be used when writing unit tests against code that is expected to throw ArgumentNullExceptions when provided with null values for arguments.

Comment: It was actually exactly for unit testing/ TestInitialize that I searched and found this answer. Your responses make sense. I wonder if an extra keyword or attribute might be a good language feature to add for this, to disengage the warning. Even allow the exclamation point to be within the definition? I have implemented your answer, but this solution still feels quite awkward.

Answer (score 0):

I really don't like the `= null!;` syntax, and I can't really pinpoint why.  It seems ugly and really unnecessary.  I don't want to update hundreds of tests.

Anyway, I did this (in Visual Studio):

1. Right click the Test project > **Properties**
2. At the top, search properties for "suppress".
3. Add CS8618 to the list separated by a semi-colon.
4. Hit Save.

I only plan to do this in test projects.  I sometimes have async code I need to use in my test setup, so I cannot initialize these members in a constructor.  *(Constructors cannot be async.)*

[image]